# File does not contain an armv7 slice

Tags: ios, xcode, armv7

I cannot build and test on devices because Xcode gives me this error:

```
ld: file is universal (2 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7 slice: /Users/------/Desktop/Running APP/------/-----/YACropImage.a file '/Users/------/Desktop/Running APP/------/-----/YACropImage.a' for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You need to upgrade your `.a` file with arvm7 bit support. May that will solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the support for any architecture, for example, ARMv7-s in your case, use menu Project -> Build Settings -> remove the architecture from "valid architectures".

You can use this as a temporary solution until the library has been updated. You have to remove the architecture from your main project, not from the library.

Alternatively, you can set the flag for your debug configuration's "Build Active Architecture Only" to Yes. Leave the release configuration's "Build Active Architecture Only" to No, just so you'll get a reminder before releasing that you ought to upgrade any third-party libraries you're using.